# Interaction not significant when using a logistic model but is significant using a poisson/negative binomial model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, interaction, mixed-models, multi-level

I ran an experiment in which participants were asked to pass a story along a 4 person 'transmission chain', a bit like the game Chinese Whispers. Person 1 reads the story and re-writes it for person 2, who does the same and it continues until all four people in the chain have read and reproduced the story. I'm interested it whether positive or negative information 'survives' better in the reproductions. I have modeled this two ways: one approach was to code each item in the original story as being either present (1) or absent (0) in the reproductions and model this using a logistic model:

```
survival.logit <- glmer(Present ~ Posn.c*mood.c*Valence.c + (1+Valence.c|mood.c/Chain.) + (1|Item), data = Survival.Analysis_restructureddata, family = binomial, glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", check.conv.grad=.makeCC("warning", 2e-3)))
```

The other approach is to count the number of each type of statement that is lost across the chains and model this data using a poisson or negative binomial model.

```
survival.count <- glmer.nb(Loss_across.Chain ~ Posn.c*mood.c*Valence.c + (1 + Valence.c|mood.c/Chain), data = FinalData_forpoisson, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", check.conv.grad = .makeCC("warning", 0.05)))
```

The fixed factors in each model are:

Posn.c - position in the chain (centered)

mood.c - mood condition (a between-groups factor, centered)

Valence.c - valence of the item (positive or negative, centered)

Both models return similar results with one key exception - the interaction between position in the chain and valence is not significant in the logistic model but is highly significant in the negative binomial model. Why might this be the case?? Graphing the data suggests that there is indeed an interaction, such that positive information is lost at a faster rate than negative across the chain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Please see below the model output for the both models:

Logistic:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Present ~ Posn.c * mood.c * Valence.c + (1 + Valence.c | mood.c/Chain.) +      (1 | Item)
   Data: Survival.Analysis_restructureddata
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", check.conv.grad = .makeCC("warning",      0.002))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  5795.2   5895.4  -2882.6   5765.2     5873 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.7595 -0.5744  0.1876  0.5450  5.5047 

Random effects:
 Groups        Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr
 Chain.:mood.c (Intercept) 7.550e-01 8.689e-01     
               Valence.c   1.366e+00 1.169e+00 0.47
 Item          (Intercept) 1.624e+00 1.274e+00     
 mood.c        (Intercept) 3.708e-18 1.926e-09     
               Valence.c   7.777e-14 2.789e-07 1.00
Number of obs: 5888, groups:  Chain.:mood.c, 92; Item, 16; mood.c, 2

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)              0.43895    0.33331   1.317   0.1879    
Posn.c                  -0.54789    0.03153 -17.378   <2e-16 ***
mood.c                  -0.23004    0.19436  -1.184   0.2366    
Valence.c                1.64397    0.65245   2.520   0.0117 *  
Posn.c:mood.c           -0.07000    0.06141  -1.140   0.2543    
Posn.c:Valence.c         0.06144    0.06301   0.975   0.3295    
mood.c:Valence.c        -0.05999    0.28123  -0.213   0.8311    
Posn.c:mood.c:Valence.c  0.01498    0.12276   0.122   0.9029    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Posn.c mood.c Vlnc.c Psn.:. Ps.:V. md.:V.
Posn.c      -0.009                                          
mood.c      -0.001  0.009                                   
Valence.c    0.025 -0.019 -0.002                            
Posn.c:md.c  0.001  0.007 -0.014 -0.001                     
Psn.c:Vlnc. -0.018  0.054 -0.002 -0.009 -0.024              
md.c:Vlnc.c -0.002 -0.002  0.399 -0.001 -0.065  0.012       
Psn.c:m.:V. -0.001 -0.024 -0.046  0.001  0.060  0.007 -0.019
```

Negative Binomial:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(5.0188)  ( log )
Formula: Loss_across.Chain ~ Posn.c * mood.c * Valence.c + (1 + Valence.c |      mood.c/Chain)
   Data: FinalData_forpoisson
Control: ..3

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1901.3   1970.4   -935.7   1871.3      721 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3727 -0.7404 -0.5037  0.4609  7.3896 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr
 Chain:mood.c (Intercept) 1.989e-13 4.46e-07     
              Valence.c   3.589e-13 5.99e-07 1.00
 mood.c       (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.00e+00     
              Valence.c   1.690e-14 1.30e-07  NaN
Number of obs: 736, groups:  Chain:mood.c, 92; mood.c, 2

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             -0.19375    0.04797  -4.039 5.37e-05 ***
Posn.c                  -0.61020    0.04124 -14.798  < 2e-16 ***
mood.c                   0.04862    0.09597   0.507  0.61242    
Valence.c               -0.27487    0.09594  -2.865  0.00417 ** 
Posn.c:mood.c           -0.04232    0.08252  -0.513  0.60803    
Posn.c:Valence.c         0.38080    0.08247   4.617 3.89e-06 ***
mood.c:Valence.c         0.13272    0.19194   0.691  0.48929    
Posn.c:mood.c:Valence.c  0.05143    0.16504   0.312  0.75534    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Posn.c mood.c Vlnc.c Psn.:. Ps.:V. md.:V.
Posn.c       0.491                                          
mood.c      -0.014  0.007                                   
Valence.c    0.030 -0.090 -0.036                            
Posn.c:md.c  0.007 -0.008  0.492 -0.021                     
Psn.c:Vlnc. -0.090  0.063 -0.021  0.491 -0.030              
md.c:Vlnc.c -0.036 -0.021  0.027 -0.014 -0.091  0.007       
Psn.c:m.:V. -0.021 -0.030 -0.091  0.007  0.060 -0.008  0.492
```

Comment: Without a reproducible example or, at the bare minimum, the model summaries, you're asking for pure speculation. This question would be much improved with either of those

Comment: Based on the model outputs, my original suspicion was correct. You have done aggregation in the second model (n= 5888 vs 736). The aggregation implies some loss of information. And the count model removes the RE for `item`. This appears to be a statistically significant RE in the logistic model though I'm not sure if it's substantively significant.

Comment: In addition, you don't appear to have the RE specified ideally (at least in the logistic). What is the LRT if you remove the 2nd level `mood.c`? ... Did you do a unconditional means model first to see what the partition of variance is?

Comment: You also appear to have some problems in your RE given the correlation of `1.00`. Do you have enough observations to estimate all these parameters? .... That is to say that **I think your model(s) is/are misspecified**

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback @Alex. I have a few questions. You're right that the second model is aggregated - I have two outcomes for each participant in the second model (count of positive and count of negative) in the second model whilst the first has 16 outcomes for each (8 x positive items and 8 x negative). You mentioned I don't have the RE specified ideally - what would you recommend?

Comment: In addition - you asked about the LRT - what is this? I'm also unsure what you mean by an unconditional means model. Do you mean a model without predictors?

Comment: Re: unconditional means model- yes, without predictors. This model is described in all major texts on HLM/MLM. This model is useful to get a baseline understanding of the partition of variance and what levels of RE are important. eg. if you had `student/classroom/school_district` but the partition of variance was ~1% for classroom you could likely drop that level (or you could do the LRT to test).

Comment: RE: random-effects-- it depends on your design. It's not clear to me that `mood.c` is a grouping factor (since I don't know what your design is). But based on the model output, it appears an unnecessary grouping-factor which you can test via [LRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test)

Comment: Thanks @Alex - yes, you're right in that mood.c turns out to be unnecessary when I compare the above models with a reduced model.

Comment: @Alex - I have another question, related to this analysis. As you point out in the above, mood is unnecessary. Therefore the best fitting model includes position in the chain (which has four levels) and valence which has two. Both of these have been centered around zero. Should I be treating position as a factor? Or given my design is treating position as a continuous predictor ok?

Comment: What do you mean that `position` and `valence` have been centered "around 0"? This seems like a meaningless statement to me. Position = {1,2,3,4} Are you saying that you've subtracted 1 from this for interpretation? Valence = {-1, 1}. Given you descriptions so far, `valence` is a factor (although a {-1,1} coding is fine.

Comment: Whether you treat `position` as a factor or an integer depends on your intended interpretation. But to be clear, integers are **not** continuous. They are integers.

Comment: Sorry @Alex. The values for Valence are now 0.5 and -0.5 and for Position (-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5). This was something my supervisor was fairly adamant I do. I'm inclined to leave Position as an integer - meaning I get a single estimate representing a one-unit change in this predictor. I'm interested in modelling change across positions, rather than specifically obtaining an estimate for each point in the chain - if that makes sense.

Comment: Change across position should be modeled with `position` not as a factor. Personally, I think the interpretation is harder, for both you and the reader, with {-1.5, -.5, .5, 1.5}, but the slope estimate should be the same for a linear effect. It would not be if you were measuring quadratic effects (which seems like a reasonable thing to explore in this model). `valence` {-.5, .5} indicates that you cannot have a neutral valence as opposed to {-1,1}.

Comment: At this point, all of your questions are substantive statistical questions and none are related to programming. It sounds like you're a grad student. I suggest you explore the resources at your school for statistical consulting.

Comment: Thanks @Alex - unfortunately I have exhausted the statistical consulting resources at my school so I'm essentially on my own here.

Comment: you can try the help pages from a consulting center that I used to work at: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/dae/. Alternatively, there are a number of good books on MLM/HLM

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I have tried both of options before - I'll try again.